# Kotlin - custom sorting of ArrayList

Tags: android, sorting, kotlin, arraylist

I am building an Android application in which I would like to implement the custom sorting of `User`

Let me explain the requirement in detail.

Let's assume that there are 15 users stored in the `ArrayList` of type `User` and each users will have separate role mapping. The users must be `grouped by roles` in the same order `as below`.

```
 1.Mechanic 
 2.Plumber 
 3.Electrician
```

Also, **within the role groups** they should be sorted primarily based on `unread message count` and secondarily based on `alphabetical order`

**Case 1: Without Unread messages**

Based on `role-based grouping` and `alphabetical sorting`(without unread messages), the users should be displayed in the following way.(The '0' in the bracket indicates the unread messages count)

```
Aarav,Mechanic(0)
Dhruv,Mechanic(0)
Jason,Mechanic(0)
Pranav,Mechanic(0)
Zeplin,Mechanic(0)

Amit,Plumber(0)
Baskaran,Plumber(0)
Garry,Plumber(0)
Rakesh,Plumber(0)
Shekar,Plumber(0)

Balu,Electrician(0)
Ragunathan,Electrician(0)
Prem kumar,Electrician(0)
Saravanan,Electrician(0)
Thanigaivel,Electrician(0)
```

**Case 2: With unread messages count**

When there are users(within role) with unread chat counts, the list should prioritize them primarily in the list and the alphabetical order should be considered as secondary. It should typically look like below.

```
Zeplin,Mechanic(20)
Pranav,Mechanic(10)
Aarav,Mechanic(0)
Dhruv,Mechanic(0)
Jason,Mechanic(0)

Garry,Plumber(5)
Rakesh,Plumber(5)
Amit,Plumber(0)
Baskaran,Plumber(0)
Shekar,Plumber(0)

Prem kumar,Electrician(10)
Balu,Electrician(0)
Ragunathan,Electrician(0)
Saravanan,Electrician(0)
Thanigaivel,Electrician(0)
```

Please help me to accomplish this.

**Below is what I have tried**

```
 fun getListWithGroupingAndSorting(){
      val users = ArrayList<User>
     // Writing logic to pull list of users from server and assigning to `users`
        return ArrayList(users.sortedWith(compareByDescending<User> {
            it.unreadMessageCount
        }.thenBy {
            it.firstName
        }))
    
    }
```

This sorts the list primarily based on unread message count and secondarily based on alphabetical order **but unable to accomplish in the above mentioned way.**

Comment: You're probably going to have to use [groupBy](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html) first, to group them.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini How to accomplish? Please help me out. first it should display if any mechanics and then Electricians and then plumbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually went into right direction. You just need to additionally sort by the role. Something like this:

```kotlin
val rolesOrder = mapOf("Mechanic" to 1, "Plumber" to 2, "Electrician" to 3)

users.sortedWith(
    compareBy<User> { rolesOrder[it.role] }
        .thenByDescending { it.unreadMessageCount }
        .thenBy { it.firstName }
)
```

If you really need to group items instead of just sorting them, so you need something like `Map<Role, List<Users>>`, then:

```kotlin
users.groupByTo(sortedMapOf(compareBy { rolesOrder[it] })) { it.role }
    .mapValues { (_, value) ->
        value.sortedWith(
            compareByDescending<User> { it.unreadMessageCount }
                .thenBy { it.firstName }
        )
    }
```

If you have an ordered list of roles and you need to assign indexes to them, you can do it like this:

```kotlin
val rolesOrder = listOf("Mechanic", "Plumber", "Electrician")
    .withIndex()
    .associate { it.value to it.index }
```

Note that if the role is missing in the `rolesOrder`, the user will be put at the beginning. If this is a possible case and you would like to put them at the end, then compare roles like this:

```kotlin
rolesOrder[it.role] ?: Integer.MAX_VALUE
```

Comment: Thank you. And, Sure, let me try this out and get back ASAP.

Comment: I have tried. The sorting based on alphabetical order and chat count work fine but the grouping does not happen :-( Please help me out.

Comment: What do you mean that grouping does not happen? Roles are ignored while sorting, so they're mixed up in the result list?

Comment: Yes. I have just tried this.val rolesOrder = mapOf("Mechanic" to 1, "Plumber" to 2, "Electrician" to 3)

users.sortedWith(
    compareBy<User> { rolesOrder[it.role] }
        .thenByDescending { it.unreadMessageCount }
        .thenBy { it.firstName }
)

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't seem possible that this code would sort while ignoring roles. Please recheck everything. Also, I assume you are aware it does not sort in-place, but instead creates another list. You did the same in your own code, so I guess this is fine.

Comment: Will this take of grouping?   users.groupByTo(sortedMapOf(compareBy { rolesOrder[it] })) { it.role }
    .mapValues { (_, value) ->
        value.sortedWith(
            compareByDescending<User> { it.unreadMessageCount }
                .thenBy { it.firstName }
        )
    }

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. You just copy&pasted my code into the comment. I know for sure that both examples for sorting and grouping work properly, because I tested them before posting. If it doesn't work for you then you probably have to add more information into the question: what is the exact code that you used, what is the result and why it is different than expected.

Comment: My bad. The keys are case-sensitive. seems that the roles from backend is in the lowercase. Thank you so much :-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe Broot's answer is fine; if you need a "working example", I'm sure there are smarter/better/more kotlin ways, but why not start simple.

In 5 minutes, you can come up with an example running [in the kotlin playground](https://pl.kotl.in/IQbHZhUqK).

Essentially:

```
data class User(val role: String, val unread: Int = 0)

fun main() {
    val unsorted = listOf(User("Mechanic", 5), 
                          User("Plumber", 3),
                          User("Electrician", 2),
                          User("Mechanic", 9),
                          User("Mechanic", 1),
                          User("Electrician", 8),
                          User("Mechanic", 4),
                          User("Plumber", 0))
    
    // Group them
    val sortedByRole = unsorted
        .groupBy { it.role }
        .forEach { k, group ->  
           val sortedGroup = group.sortedByDescending { user -> user.unread }
           println(sortedGroup)
        } 
}
```

Output:

```
[User(role=Mechanic, unread=9), User(role=Mechanic, unread=5), User(role=Mechanic, unread=4), User(role=Mechanic, unread=1)]
[User(role=Plumber, unread=3), User(role=Plumber, unread=0)]
[User(role=Electrician, unread=8), User(role=Electrician, unread=2)]
```